# React component, which containing VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have programmed a **text editor** (whole generated by JS, basically wysiwyg, it return output in html) in VanillaJS and now I am learning React. I made a "document" component, which contains "paper" components, but now I want to **connect these two things - paper (in React) and the text editor (JavaScript).**

**So my questions are:**
Is this a good practice? If it is, then how to propely connect these two things? And if it is not, should I remake the text editor into React? React does not seems to me like a great choice for such a problem, but I am pretty lame in it.

It would be perfect if the solution would be good for saving the generated html into database.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Well after one month I think I am ready to answer...**

In generally it is not a good idea to combinate Vanilla JS and React (it's perfectly good to use VanillaJS function, which are not used for DOM, both using different access to DOM, code is messy and you lose some advantage of React)

And React is a really good choice for this, especially with draft.js. But it is also possible to use React with `contentEditable`attribute, however you can a have problem with Controlled Components https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html so **I would definitely recommend using draft.js**, which doesn't have these problems and even Facebook using it everywhere, where they need a rich text editor.